# I am having trouble with compiler flags on Code::blocks. Beginner to programming

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I am a beginner at programming, learning from the book "C++ For Dummies".

In the beginning of the book it tells me to select 3 compiler flags in the compiler settings.

1. Enable extra compiler settings
2. Have g++ follow the coming C++0x ISO C++ language standard
3. Have g++ follow the C++11ISO C++ Language standard.

I am able to select the first option no problem.
However with the 2 g++ options I am only able to select one of them.

Is there a way I could select both there are no errors while im learning out of the book?

Comment: It's nonsense to select two versions of c++ to use at the same time.

Comment: C++0x is C++11 before it was standardized. Just select C++11 and go ahead.

Comment: You might want to get a more recent edition of that book. There have been a lot of changes and there will be less confusion using a more current edition.

Comment: Doug, I don't believe there is a newer version of the book I currently have...

Answer (score 3):

### TL;DR

---

Choose C++11 and you'll be fine.

---

They are all language standards, so you can only choose either one of them.

Also, C++ Language standards are backward compatible, this meant using a newer standard (C++14, which is a standard distributed in 2014, hence the name) would always include former standards.

(Note that there few are exceptions, like deprecated ones. But you don't really need to worry about that since deprecated one most likely have replacements and the compiler would also kindly warn you)

Now back to why you can't compile with C++11 and C++0x

1. C++0x is like a draft version of C++11, if you see any English characters after C++, they are likely to be draft standard rather then official standards. There's not much reason to use C++0x rather then C++11.
2. Since all standards are most likely backward compatible, there's not much reason to compile in an older standard. Of course, you might ask why not always compile in the newer version? The reason is that not all compilers have implemented the newer standards. So if you need backward compiler compatibility then choose an older standard like C++98 (distributed in 1998). Otherwise, I personally recommend compiling in newer standards or at least C++11.

For more info on C++ Language Standards here's a wiki page for you:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B#Standardization

Also if you want to know more about C++, a reference manual can be found here:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/

Comment: When it isn't backwards compatible (C++11's change in the `auto` keyword for example) it is very heavily documented and marked by compiler warnings where possible.

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you!